# Symfony's Prevent RCE when calling untrusted remote with CachingHttpClient error

Tags: php, symfony, security

I got the following error when trying to do `composer install --no-progress` within deployment:

```
1 packages have known vulnerabilities.
!!  
!!  symfony/http-kernel (v5.0.7)
!!  ----------------------------
!!  
!!   * [CVE-2020-15094][]: Prevent RCE when calling untrusted remote with CachingHttpClient
!!  
!!  [CVE-2020-15094]: https://symfony.com/cve-2020-15094
```

Following this link provided in my error: https://symfony.com/blog/cve-2020-15094-prevent-rce-when-calling-untrusted-remote-with-cachinghttpclient

It navigates me to the following github link here: https://github.com/symfony/symfony/commit/ba3975329149cddebfe969f70b2577b0e37d1e76

What does that mean for local development and the fix associated to it? I tried following the link: src/Symfony/Component/HttpClient/Tests/CachingHttpClientTest.php

My project doesn't have that link

[image]

So how do I fix this issue? How does one update issues that come up moving forward? I'm using a mac set up.

Comment: 1) What is your issue? You mention "my error", but I don't see an error anywhere in the question. 2) Symfony source code is not in your `src` (that's reserved for your app). It is in the `vendor` folder.

Comment: Updated the question to reflect said error.

Comment: Also @El_Vanja even within the `vendor` folder, it doesn't have the paths that the github page says should be updated.

Comment: You're running a version that didn't receive the patch (the linked article states `The issue has been fixed in Symfony 4.4.13 and 5.1.5. Symfony 4.3 and 5.0 won't be patched as they are not maintained anymore.`). Consider upgrading Symfony. The sooner you stop running an unmaintained version, the better.

Comment: And in that same article, they specifically state that the linked patch is for 4.4, so these structure differences are understandable.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The best way to move forward is to update to a later Symfony version. 5.0 is not maintained anymore, you can use 5.1 or 5.2. If you are not the one responsible for updating dependencies on the project, you may want to report this to the person who is.

If you look at the page linked in the error itself (https://symfony.com/cve-2020-15094) you can read:

> The issue has been fixed in Symfony 4.4.13 and 5.1.5. Symfony 4.3 and 5.0 won't be patched as they are not maintained anymore.

To update Symfony you can follow this link: https://symfony.com/doc/current/setup/upgrade_minor.html

Comment: Ok that makes a lot of sense. Thank you for the great help!